# Cannot access/read index in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, indexing

So this is the culprit

```
mysql_query("UPDATE coordrating SET submissions = '2' WHERE rating = 2");
```

Now this works fine UNLESS I try to use the index (which is the index of my table) values.
So this doesn't work:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE coordrating SET index = '2' WHERE rating = 2");
```

or

```
mysql_query("UPDATE coordrating SET submissions = '2' WHERE index = 2");
```

This is the screenshot of my database structure

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/694/problemmysql.png/

I'm completely baffled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
UPDATE `coordrating` SET `index` = '2' WHERE `rating` = 2
```

Backquotes are used to delimit table or field names, because sometimes table or fieldname can match MySQL operator.

Answer (score 1):

Those queries don't work because `index` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html). You can quote that name using backticks to tell MySQL that it should be treated as a name and not a reserved word:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE coordrating SET `index` = '2' WHERE rating = 2");

mysql_query("UPDATE coordrating SET submissions = '2' WHERE `index` = 2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "index" column (one best practice is to use **id** as name of column used as primary key), as viewable in your screenshot, is pimary key. One costrain of *Primary key* is to be **unique**, so it's probable that you will have 2 row having "rating = 2" so your query will fail because of unique constrain.

Another best practice is to avoid to change the primary key value, use another column.